# Can I fork another persons repo twice into my own account?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

On GitHub, I can't seem to figure out how I can fork a repo twice into one account.

So there is a repo from Bob/CoolFramework

I fork it to Jeremy/MyShooter and start to build a game

Now I also want to fork it to Jeremy/MyRPG to build another new game

When I try to fork CoolFramework a second time, it just takes me to MyShooter.

So the options I can think of:
A) I'm not using Git in the right way
B) It's not possible on Git
C) I just couldn't see the option on Github

Comment: This sounds like you should not be forking. Forking is *modifying* a project, not building off of it

Comment: Can you show the exact commands you're running?

Comment: I'm currently just doing it off an internal github.com implementation.
@bengoesboom, I want to build off the base project. Should I do something other than fork?

Comment: What’s wrong with just cloning the “parent” repository, and then pushing to a different remote?

Comment: @JeremyLee It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish. If you are not modifying the framework, use a sub-module. If you want to modify the framework and use the same modifications in both games, fork and then include your fork as a submodule. If you are just building entirely different things that are based off of the framework but significantly change the framework, you might want to clone

Comment: This still seems like a limitation of github. Another example: suppose I think a single repo should be refactored into two separate repos. I'd like both of those to say "forked from ..." but Github apparently doesn't support this. Just a UI limitation, really.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your case, I would suggest going with [submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279658/403401). However to answer your exact question, here's how you should proceed.

1. Start by creating `Jeremy/MyShooter` and `Jeremy/MyRPG` on Github. Keep them empty.
2. Clone your origin project on your system, twice, giving it different names

   ```
   $ git clone http://github.com/Bob/CoolFramework MyShooter
   $ git clone http://github.com/Bob/CoolFramework MyRPG
   ```
3. You now have 2 different local repos pointing to the same origin. You should remove the origin and point to yours as a remote:

   ```
   $ cd MyShooter
   $ git remote remove origin
   $ git remote add origin http://github.com/Jeremy/MyShooter.git
   $ git push -u origin master
   ```
4. Don't forget to do the same for `MyRPG`

Comment: Thanks rahmu. I ended up not using submodules and just cloned the repo as you said. The framework I was intending to fork was really made to be built off of, and not just used a submodule.

Comment: Is there any way to make a pull request when you do this?

Comment: `remove`&`add` origin is same as `set-url`?

Answer (score 2):

From the sound of things, you are using a framework within a game you are creating. If you are just *using* the framework and not *changing* it, create a new project for your game and include the framework project within it as a [sub-module](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Assuming you are not modifying the framework, you should not be forking it. Forking a project is for modifying (often with the intent of submitting your fork to be merged back into the source project).

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to *fork* a repo twice on Github (as of late 2021) but if you want to *build on* the same repo multiple times, you can use the "Import Repository" option and feed it the URL used to clone.