# How to submit a PR against a now-broken upstream?

Tags: git, github

I'm a Git(Hub) neophyte.

I forked, changed and submitted a PR against a GitHub repo (R'). The PR has not been reviewed|accepted.

Meanwhile I wanted to submit a separate (non-overlapping) PR and followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279822/609290) to create a 2nd copy of the remote repo in my GitHub account (R").

I wrote the code and committed the changes to it (R") but I'm unable to submit a PR using the GitHub UI.

[image]

Am I screwed?
Or is there a way I can add back the original origin so that I may submit the PR?

I Googled around and tried:

`git remote add upstream https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community.git`

But that made no difference.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to "fork" twice: from the local clone of your first fork, you can simply

- create another branch (from upstream/master),
- make a second patch in that branch,
- push that second branch
- make a second PR from said second branch on your GitHub fork.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I should do and should have done. I think the problem I've created for myself is that applied my first set of changes to master on R' and now, by forking, when I submit a PR for the forked (distinct) code, it pulls through the changes I made to the master too; I should have forked twice to keep each distinct.