# Is there a way to clone a repo twice on github?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Note: This is NOT THE SAME as this question, before you flag me as duplicate, because I need to modify the engine, not just use it. I want to apply different sets of changes to the two repos: [Can I fork another persons repo twice into my own account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279490/can-i-fork-another-persons-repo-twice-into-my-own-account)

I want to do a project using an engine. I will have to modify this engine to make my project, but I want it to be counted as a fork so that I can just pull to get the updates in the engine repo. Besides, I also want to be able to contribute to the engine repo for other modifications (using another fork with my changes), without pushing the changes I made for my project, which are not the ones I want to contribute to the engine. Illustration:

Lets's say I use ioquake3:

`ioq3/ioquake3
 |--spooikypok-dev/ioquake3contributions
 |--spooikypok-dev/projectWithioquake3`

Is there a way I can do this or another way to do such a plan?

Comment: Not sure how your question differs from the question you linked to: you want two different forks, ans that's what the linked question is about. But anyway, you don't need two forks, nor two clones. All you need is two branches: one where you develop your own changes, and one where you develop your contributions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I fork another persons repo twice into my own account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279490/can-i-fork-another-persons-repo-twice-into-my-own-account)

Comment: No, because I need to modify the engine, not just use it. I want to apply different sets of changes to the two repos.